# How can I store an image in a JSON feed?

Tags: json, image, storage

I want to include images in a JSON format data feed. So I can transfer images to the client.

Comment: You can store the URL of the image, but an actual image can't be sent through JSON unless you somehow managed to encode it as a string (or an array of strings, etc) and decode it later on. See [JSON data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is text-based, so there is no standard way to include other types of data. You can however 'translate' an image (or any other binary content) to a Base64 string which can be included in a JSON feed.

This code is based of a [very good blogpost of Jerry Nixon](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/11/reading-and-writing-base64-in-windows.html).

Add these usings to the class where you add these methods: System.IO, Windows.UI.Xaml.Media, System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime and Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.
In my case I've implemented a static class with static methods.

```
    private static async Task<string> ToBase64(StorageFile bitmap)
    {
        var stream = await bitmap.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        var bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();
        return await ToBase64(bytes, (uint)decoder.PixelWidth, (uint)decoder.PixelHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY);
    }

    private static async Task<string> ToBase64(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
    {
        var bytes = (await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync()).ToArray();
        return await ToBase64(bytes, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight);
    }

    private static async Task<string> ToBase64(byte[] image, uint height, uint width, double dpiX = 96, double dpiY = 96)
    {
        // encode image
        var encoded = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, encoded);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, height, width, dpiX, dpiY, image);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
        encoded.Seek(0);

        // read bytes
        var bytes = new byte[encoded.Size];
        await encoded.AsStream().ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        // create base64
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    public async static Task<string> ConvertFileToBase64(StorageFile file)
    {
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        var pixels = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
        var bytes = pixels.DetachPixelData();
        return await ToBase64(bytes, (uint)decoder.PixelWidth, (uint)decoder.PixelHeight, decoder.DpiX, decoder.DpiY);
    }

    public static async Task<ImageSource> FromBase64(string base64)
    {
        // read stream
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        var image = bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream();

        // decode image
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(image);
        image.Seek(0);

        // create bitmap
        var output = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelHeight, (int)decoder.PixelWidth);
        await output.SetSourceAsync(image);
        return output;
    }
```